# How to handle multiple async calls at a time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Actually I made an android application in which I retrieving data from server in JSON form and I'm using async calls for getting data. The data retrieving is OK.
But there is a problem: my application has only one screen in which there are two fragments, and in both fragments I'm getting data from JSON response which is handled async task.
Application is by default on fragment 1 and fragment has dynamic elements when I click on an element. A new activity opens and in new activity I retrieve some more data from database. Now when I open the activity the data shows up in no time.
When I go back and switch to the fragment 2 and then again switch to fragment 1 and then again click on any element the data is retrieved after few seconds.
Then I again switch to 2nd fragment and then again 1st one and click on any element the data retrieving time increases more.
Every time I repeat this step the retrieving time of data is increasing. Same is the case with 2nd fragment.
Now I want a solution to tacking this time problem. I need your suggestions. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your code, so that we can figure out the problem in your code?

Comment: @AmitTiwary if u want we can have a teamviewer session because it is whole project not a few lines of code

Comment: You can upload your code on Github and share the link here so that other people can also help you.